# How to put abbreviation letters to the querys?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am setting up a query but I need to add abbreviated letters to the tables, this is an example of what I need to do:

```
SELECT  E.CodCli AS Clave,C.Nombre as Responsable, C.NombreCorto as [Nombre Comercial],E.Articulo,P.Producto,P1.Producto Envase,SUM(E.Cantidad) Entregados,SUM(E.Devuelto) Devueltos,SUM(E.Cantidad)-SUM(E.Devuelto) Saldo 
FROM    DevEnvases E INNER JOIN Clientes C ON E.CodCli=C.IdCli Inner Join Productos P ON E.Articulo=P.Clave Inner Join Productos P1 ON E.Envase=P1.Clave
```

this is my query

```
  def self.busqueda_general(params)
   query = select('[devenvases].CodCli,[clientes].Nombre,[clientes].NombreCorto,[devenvases].Articulo,[productos].Producto')
              .joins("inner join clientes on devenvases.CodCli=clientes.IdCli inner join productos on devenvases.Articulo=productos.Clave")
              .group(:Id,:CodCliente,:Devol,:Fecha,:Status,:Ruta,:Vendedor,:Items,:KG,:Docto,:Cancelada, :IdEmpresa, :Subtotal, :Total, :IVA)
                      .where("(devenvases.Tipo = 'Venta')AND(devenvases.Ruta = :rutaId or :rutaId = '') AND (devenvases.diao = :diao or :diao = '')",{rutaId: params[:search], diao: params[:diao]})
                      .distinct
  end
```

Comment: Why do you need to use abbreviated table names and cannot just use the full names?

Comment: @spickermann thanks for answer. Because this is a part of the query (the first query of my publication) in which I use the same table twice. Is P to products and P1 to products, only that P has a value type in 0 and P1 in 1 and I need both registers.